# Unwanted URL_patterns dynamically added

Tags: python, django, nginx, openstreetmap

I am running a Django umap project via nginx on location /app.
That's why I changed all the URL patterns to have a ^app/ as a prefix inside the **urls.py** file.

And those actively changed URLs do work as expected. Unfortunately some URL patterns seem to be added dynamically such as a language code URL which is the one I need to use.

Here is the error I am getting:

```
Using the URLconf defined in umap.urls, Django tried these URL patterns, in this order:
^app/admin/
^login/(?P<backend>[^/]+)/$ [name='begin']
^complete/(?P<backend>[^/]+)/$ [name='complete']
^disconnect/(?P<backend>[^/]+)/$ [name='disconnect']
^disconnect/(?P<backend>[^/]+)/(?P<association_id>[^/]+)/$ [name='disconnect_individual']
^app/m/(?P<pk>\d+)/$ [name='umap_short_url']
^app/ajax-proxy/$ [name='ajax-proxy']
^en/
^uploads\/(?P<path>.*)$
^static\/(?P<path>.*)$
The current URL, app/en/map/vas_6, didn't match any of these.
```

As you can see, the ^en/ URL_pattern does not have the required prefix.

I am failing to find the location when this URL_pattern is added. Is there a way to just add a prefix to ALL of the URL_patterns?

**EDIT

Here is the nginx conf file:

```
server {
  listen 80;
  server_name domain.org;

  location / {
    root /opt/my-nodejs-project/;
    proxy_pass http://127.0.0.1:3000;
    proxy_redirect default;
  }

  location /app/ {
    root /opt/my-django-project/umap/;
    proxy_pass http://127.0.0.1:8000;
    proxy_redirect default;
  }

  location /static/ {
    alias /opt/my-django-project/umap/;
    proxy_pass http://127.0.0.1:8000;
    proxy_redirect default;
  }

}
```

Comment: Can we see the nginx config file for this?

Comment: @JavierBuzzi here you go

Comment: i think you need to add `/app` to your `proxy_pass` should look like this: `proxy_pass http://127.0.0.1:8000/app`